# KeyListener working only on debugger,but dosen't on Run

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have weird problem, my application doesn't work on 'run', but only while debugging.

Im trying to start game while pressing button, but then keyListener dosent work(it does work correctly while debugging). I have 3 panel, the first one is for logining, and after clicking button it should start game and remove current panel. The second and third are for score area and game area. When im opening game without LoginPanel it does work fine. Do u have any ideas what can be wrong?

```
public LoginPanel(MainFrame mainFrame)
{
    this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    makeGIU();

}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this); // draw the image
}

private void makeGIU()
{
    this.img = new ImageIcon(SOURCE).getImage();
    setDimension();
    button = new JButton("OK");
    nickLabel = new JLabel("<html>SOKOBANA<br>TOMASZ JANIEC<br>KACPER KUSTRA</html>", JLabel.CENTER);
    nickLabel.setFont(new Font("Gloria Hallelujah",Font.PLAIN,20));
    nickLabel.setSize(100,50);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    button.addActionListener(evt -> {
        mainFrame.remove(this);
        mainFrame.newGameStart();
        mainFrame.revalidate();
    });
    this.setPreferredSize(Size);
    this.add(button);
    this.add(nickLabel);
    this.add(nickText);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
public MainFrame() {
    setTitle(TITLE);
    setVisible(true);
    setBounds(new Rectangle(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HIGHT));
    makeMenu();
    this.setResizable(true);
    //newGameStart(); // this does work
    this.add(new LoginPanel(this)); // this dosent
    revalidate();
}


public void newGameStart() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable(this, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HIGHT, mapNames) {
        });
        t.start();

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) and/or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a key listener on the JPanel and than with an if statement you can set which key want to control